# Multiple requests with useFetch

Tags: reactjs, use-http

Im sending 2 requests at the same time using useFetch, **on Safari the responses are getting mixed**

```
const [entries,setEntries] = useState([]);
const [categories,setCategories] = useState([]);

const { get, response} = useFetch('https://api.publicapis.org');


const getData = useCallback( async()=>{
    const entriesRes = await get('/entries?category=animals&https=true')
    if(response.ok)
        setEntries(entriesRes.entries)
},[])

const getCategories = useCallback( async()=>{
    const categoriesRes = await get('/categories')
    if(response.ok)
        setCategories(categoriesRes)
},[])


useEffect(()=>{
    getData();
    getCategories();
},[])
```

if the getCategories returns first the response go to entriesRes instand of categoriesRes this happens only on safari

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming the useFetch results:

```
const [entries,setEntries] = useState([]);
const [categories,setCategories] = useState([]);

const categoryFetch = useFetch('https://api.publicapis.org');
const dataFetch = useFetch('https://api.publicapis.org');



const getData = useCallback( async()=>{
    const entriesRes = await dataFetch.get('/entries?category=animals&https=true')
    if(response.ok)
        setEntries(entriesRes.entries)
},[])

const getCategories = useCallback( async()=>{
    const categoriesRes = await categoryFetch.get('/categories')
    if(response.ok)
        setCategories(categoriesRes)
},[])


useEffect(()=>{
    getData();
    getCategories();
},[])
```